# UWP simulator doesn't work after Creators Update 1709 (VS 2017)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Infinite loading of the simulator, I see the running dots and nothing more. Yesterday I installed Creators Update 1709, the application compiled without errors and works by opening the .exe file, I used VS 2017 Community and Windows 10 Home for one language

Comment: Any exceptions? Did you have a screenshot ?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT any eta? I'm experiencing this problem as well.